# How to read password related information in Windows using Java?

Tags: java

I am fairly new to programming in Java. Can someone tell me or simply point to some good links to show how to read password related information on Windows systems? For example, password history, password max/min age, password length and so on.

Are there good Java libraries that can do this job?

Comment: I might suggest looking a the [JNA Libraries](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). Not positive the calls are in there, but it would be the first place I'd check. Also, if you find the Windows API calls and JNA does not already provide the interface, you can fairly easily add the needed code.

Comment: Or possibly you need to look it up in Active Directory, which you can do via JNDI.

Comment: My objective is to fetch a number of different information from the Windows systems, not just password. Things like filesystems, permission checks and so on. What is the easiest way to do this job? I googled for more information on JNA but it seems the documentation is limited? Any good online tutorials with plenty of examples?

Comment: @Trevor What are you asking is really very Windows specific. If the the Windows environment is part of AD (Actvie Directory) domain, most of the information you want is in the AD controller (you can access the data as LDAP user attributes - as EJP mentioned). If you have a standalone Windows, JNA may be your best option. JNA is a way how to call platform specific libraries (DLL for Windows). It means "write your code as a DLL in C/C++" and call it from Java.